# GCC, PIE, PIC, archives and shared objects - what works with what?

Tags: gcc

I have a question about GCC, ThreadSanitizer and the use of archives, shared libraries and PIE and PIC.

I've been reading about as best I can all morning, but I just can't find useful, clear information on-line.

I understand what PIC does.  I think I understand that PIE is if you like an optimized version of PIC, which is only for executables.

Now come the questions...

1. Can I compile an executable with PIC, rather than PIE?
2. If I compile a shared library (.so) with PIC, must I then use PIC with any executable which uses that library, rather than PIE?
3. If I compile an archive (.a), can I use PIE?  (I have read -static and -pie should not be used together, which implies not).

I'm using ThreadSanitizer.  This requires PIC (and perhaps PIE is okay too - but as you can see, I'm not clear about this).  I have a library, which can be compiled as an archive (.a) or a shared library (.so).  The library needs to use ThreadSanitizer.  However, the binary which uses it also needs to use ThreadSanitizer (as it has some code of its own which needs checking).

The library when built as a shared library in fact fails to link when used wih ThreadSanitizer - I think the link is failing to link to libtsan (but this is I suspect not a real library, but a bunch of compiler instrincs built into GCC).  This is almost certainly me getting something wrong somewhere.

What I really want to do is use an archive (.a) since the binary is a test programme and should be able to compile without the library being installed (so users can conveniently check/test the library - the makefile for the test binary has a hard coded path to the archive binary).

If I can use PIE with archives (.a), then I'd PIE the library and the test binary.   If PIE cannot be used with archives, then I think I need to use PIC with both the library and test binary.  I don't want to use a shared library at all, since ThreadSanitizer uses TLS (thread local store) heavily and shared libraries with PIC have absolutely terrible TLS performance.

Comment: Why would a static library ever has the concept of pic or non-pic? It's not code meant to be run, but code meant to be copied. -static is about linking with a static library not making a static library.

Answer (score 8):

Ultimate functionality of pic and pie are same but in gcc -fpic is used to create shared libraries whereas -fpie is used to for exes.

1. No you cannot use pic for an executable
2. Shared libraries don't care where pie (PIE just make the exec position independent) or normal execs are using it. It is dynamic linker's (ld.so) job to link the shared library.
3. No you can't make a exec position independent while using a static library. When you link a exec with static library it creates a dependency on exec and the symbols have to be resolved at compile-time.So in short you can't.

Comment: So... if I have a shared library which needs to be position independent, and it needs to be used by a exe which also needs to be position independent, I need to build the shared library with -fPIC (or -fpic, if I can get away with it) and the executable with -fPIE?  and I *cannot* build an archive, since archives cannot be position independent.  Why can't archives be position independent, though, if an executable can be?  I can't see a difference between compiling all C files in one go and producing an exe, and compiling half into an archive and linking to the rest when they're compiled.

Comment: Shame you're only going to get one or two upvotes for this - it's a complex subject and I think most people don't know the answer.  The SO voting system is obviously broken.

Comment: From what I've been reading, I suspect PIC can be used for executables.  Also, I think static libraries can be position independent.  I begin to think when people write that PIE cannot be used with static libraries, they mean *non-PIC static libraries*...

Comment: @John-static libraries cannot be position independent this is the reason why they called static libraries(archive(.a) is collection of static libraries). When you compile a static library compiles resolves all the symbols( e.g global variables or function addresses) at compile time and allocate them a static address. But whereas in position independent shared libraries(load time shared libs also exists though) compiler resolves only those symbols which are available in that library(library can call other libs also).

Comment: To be more specific compiled static libs are just object files(not linked) and when linked with some code create a static exe.

Comment: Yes pie cannot be used with static libs.

Comment: There’s a newer GCC option to statically-link position-independent executables: `-static-pie`.